# Electric window pulls cable out of lift carriage

Tags: toyota, power-windows

I have a 1992 Toyota (Corona/Caldina) the electric window mechanism consists of a motor with a pulley that has a metal cable which seems pretty standard. The cable that goes into the regulator carriage pulls out one end when it hits the top limit.

[image]

After I figured out what had happened I put it back together and tried again and once the window got to the top it pulls the cable out of the regulator carriage. I can't see any damage where the end of the cable goes so I am not even sure how this is happening. It just seems the slightest bit of tension pops it out.

Why is it doing this?